# Conflict: The requested update for the Job is not allowed. The job already has a pending action

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I have job in azure automation
it is stucked on queued status for over and hour

When I want to cancel it through UI i get the following message:

> Conflict: The requested update for the Job is not allowed. The job
>   already has a pending action.

I get the same message when using powershell stop-azurermautomationjob by id

```
Stop-AzureRmAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Id $jobId -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design that you cannot take an action on a job while in queued state. However It shouldn't be in queued state for more than 30 mins. A recommended option is to make a copy of the code, delete the runbook and then recreate with the copied code. If you continue to see this issue, please raise a support request with Azure technical support and provide the JobId for further investigation.